# Nginx status code with error_page + multiple proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I have a simple AWS Lambda image generator that saves images to S3 for caching. On my server I use nginx to check if the requested image has already been generated or not. Then either serve it or pass request to Lambda to generate it.

Simplified nginx config:

```
location ~/img/(.*)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|webp|svg)$ {

    # check file on S3
    proxy_pass https://S3Url.com; 
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    # if not found, use generator 
    error_page 404 @image_proxy; 
}

location @image_proxy {

    # ... do some rewrites ...

    # pass request to Lambda image generator
    proxy_pass https://LambdaUrl.com;
    proxy_redirect off;

}
```

Now, when image does not exist on S3, request gets passed to Lambda function correctly, which then returns the image with 200 status code (or error message with 404 / 500 if neccessary). However, when image needs to be generated, my browser always shows 404 status code (result of first proxy_pass, not the second one from @image_proxy).

I could always rewrite error_page to `error_page 404 =200 @image_proxy` which would show nicely in a browser, but it would not solve the issue as the generator may also encounter errors or missing files and needs to be able  to return 404 or 500.

How do I make nginx to return status code of the `proxy_pass https://LambdaUrl.com;`? I would expect that to be default behavior ... if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to return the actual status of the second proxy, try: `error_page 404 = @image_proxy;` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page))

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I could have missed this ...

Comment: I am trying the same thing but not working for me.

Comment: location /  {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;

            error_page 404 = @fallback;
        }

        location @fallback {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }